# JQVMap Event (Mouse Position)

Tags: jqvmap

How to Get the mouse position, in "onRegionOver:function(event,code,region)" in jqvmap???

The event object in the function, doesn't have the properties from mouse position.
I need show a div, with extra country information, when the mouse overs the region.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

First of all I am not sure if this is a right approach or not. If you open the `jquery.vmap.js` plugin file, check out this code:

```
if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    jQuery(params.container).trigger(regionMouseOverEvent, [code, mapData.pathes[code].name]);
```

Change the code of the following line to:

```
jQuery(params.container).trigger(regionMouseOverEvent, [e, code, mapData.pathes[code].name]);
```

This event `e` is passed as a parameter to the function in the plugin. And in your call back function add one more parameter

```
onRegionOver:function(event,e,code,region){
    alert(e.pageX,"_",e.pageY);
}
```

This worked for me...Hope this Helps for you